# how to selecting image from list view and display it in image view?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am  creating a application which contains a `listView` on lefthand side that display different images now i want to show that particular image in the center of the screen when user clicks on any image in `listView`.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom adapter for your listview and add an onitemselectedlistener where inside it you can get the image you put in the view, and set the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the list of `path` of images and when user taps you will get the postion from `OnItemClickListener`. Using the `position` you can load the image from path.

The [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) has good content on creating custom adapters , You should use that then just map your path and positons. try that and post when you are stuck